# Limiting Distribution of Bernoulli to Poisson. ISI-PCB-NC$9$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

**Question:** Let $X_i\sim (i.i.d.)$, Bernoulli($\frac{\lambda}{n}$), $n\ge \lambda\ge 0$.
$Y_i\sim (i.i.d.)$, Poisson($\frac{\lambda}{n}$). $\{X_i\}$ and $\{Y_i\}$ are independent.
Define $T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i$ and $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}Y_i$. Find the limiting distribution of $\frac{T_n}{S_n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

**My solution:**
Let $p=\frac{\lambda}{n}$
$T_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i=\binom{n^2}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n^2-k}$ for some $n\ge k\ge 0$.
Similarly, $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n^2}X_i=\binom{n^2}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n^2-k}$ for some $n\ge k\ge 0$

Hence, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{T_n}{S_n}=1.$

Is there any mistake in the solution? Please help me to correct it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some mistakes in your solution. First of all, you are confusing random variables with probability mass functions. Then, $S_n$ does not have the probability mass function you wrote down. It is also Poisson distributed. Lastly, just because two random have the same probability mass function doesn't imply that their fraction converges to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your representation of $T_n$ is wrong. You should not mix up the discrete densities and the random variables.

Here is how I would solve it:

The sum of independent Poisson random variables is again Poisson distributed with the sum of the Parameters. This means $S_n$ can be written as sum
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$$
of independent random variables $Z_i$, where $Z_i$ is Poisson distributed with Parameter $\lambda$. By the law of large numbers we have then, that
$$ \frac 1 n S_n \to \mathbb E [Z_1] = \lambda$$
almost surely as $n\to\infty$.

Furthermore, in the same manner we can write
$$T_n = \sum_{i=1}^n R^n_i$$
with $R^n_i$ Binomial distributed with Parameters $n$ and $\frac \lambda n$. The Poisson approximation yields that $R_i^n$ converge to a Poisson distribution with Parameter $\lambda$. With this, the law of large numbers, and maybe something like the Skorokhod's representation theorem one should be able to show that
$\frac 1 n T_n \to \lambda $ at least in distribution. It follows then with the Slutsky theorem that $\frac{T_n}{S_n} \to 1$ in distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But there are $n^2$ terms in both the summations.

Comment: No, in my sums there are $n$ terms. This is exactly the idea.
$Z_i = \sum_{k= (i-1)n}^{in} X_k$ and $R_i^n = \sum_{k=(i-1)n}^{in}$

Comment: So, $Z_i$'s and $R_i^n$'s won't be $(i.i.d.)$?

Comment: For fixed $n\in \mathbb N$ the $(Z_i)_{i=1, \ldots , n}$, $(R^n_i)_i$ are i.i.d. families.